# being on-hold is not intentional

Tags: discussion

Besides, so many thanks to meta users and other users for their helps and guidance. But I think, some decisions discourage new users. I think, if any user or new user knows where is his/her mistakes, he/she doesn't have to write their questions. Although, some questions seems to be too simple for professional users, but maybe for other users who don't know their mistakes, are big problems. For this reason, they ask their questions. No users have to answer stupid questions but I think all of us have to respect each others and don't discourage each others. I write any question to which I have encountered and they were 'on hold'!! AS long as writing questions takes a long time for not English-language users, there are not any references to clarify the border between be on-hold and not be on-hold. I think no user want to be on hold, they ask which they don't know! Unknown problems are big problems not simple questions.

Comment: The site does explicitly have an expectation of ["some proof of a minimal Mathematica knowledge,"](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and I think some questions should be discouraged. It was this advanced-beginner-plus expectation the site has that attracted me to it. It meant I could click on a question and probably learn something about *Mathematica* and fields in which it is applied. Many users are professionals and may carry with them expectations of professionalism. I can appreciate that. Respecting them, their time, and their interest in the site is important for me....

Comment: ...For some others, anything that gives the right answer is fine, whether good or bad practice. The bad in particular deserves to be discouraged. My feeling from seeing comments about other sites is that this is one of the more tolerant and welcoming ones (fwtw). I'm a sucker for someone who needs help. [Even when I'm totally clueless what they're asking](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/87782/plotting-with-2-variables-and-given-list-of-fu-v-values#comment239007_87782), I'll write and rewrite a comment trying to figure out how to help.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I believe the word `proof` is an unfortunate choice. I don't think we need a "proof", it's the OP who needs a minimal Mma knowledge to be able to get some profit from the answers

Answer (score 15):

Having a question put on hold is neither a disgrace nor a punishment. It is simply a matter site house-keeping.

In your case, you got answers in comments to both questions that were put on hold. You, yourself, acknowledged that the answers were useful to you. The questions were put on hold and will be later closed simply because they have no long term value. The answers you got were useful to you, but they aren't useful to future visitors, so there is no reason for them to clutter up the site in the long term.

Because you did get useful answers, I don't see you have anything to complain about.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your answer. I did not have any complaint. Unfortunately, this is misunderstanding, In my view, holding-on and being accompanied with a text adhered to questions seems to be a disgrace. I just wanted to say simplicity is completely relative. Not only for Mathematica, but also in the normal life, people obtain the biggest lessons from the smallest mistakes. Perhaps my complaint is: the explanation adhered to answers is too less. For this reason, a small mistake will be repeated again and again.  However, almost answers remove problems but don't have a deeply explanations.

Comment: @mr.0093. I strongly believe that any reasonable question should receive an answer. And I agree that answering simple questions asked by beginner may have more impact on future visitors than specialized questions asked by advanced users. Also, a formal answer is better than one given in a comment. However, sometimes an answer in a comment is the best we can do. This is a volunteer operated site; there is no compelling anyone to make a formal answer. There have been several exhortations on this meta site for more formal answers and fewer comments, but positive response has been limited.

Comment: I am so glad that you are an open-minded Meta. I wish, good answers (specially for beginner users questions) will be accompanied with an explanation (even short) however I know it takes time. and I know that it is not a duty. But it causes many other users who almost are novice not only have removed problem but also learn deeply new things to prevent future mistakes. Thank you and other users for your attentions.

Comment: @mr.0093 I think you are diverging to a different topic that probably deserves its own question here on meta - something like "Should the answers to beginners' questions contain explanations?"

Comment: You are right, but the subjects are too entangled.

Answer (score 13):

I agree that having a question put on hold is not a disgrace, provided that the OP receives useful information.  Nonetheless, I have sympathy for new users.  Certainly, my first question should have been put on hold, based on the standards that we now seem to be applying.

What does concern me are rude comments that too often are made to new users.  Fortunately, I was not the target of rude comments when I asked my first, less than inspired, question but instead received two informative answers.  I try to follow the example of those two users and hope that others do too.

Comment: You can flag comments that you think are rude, of course.